# backing buffer in Android Bitmap class

Tags: buffer, backing

When I looked at the implementation of Bitmap class of Android,
I found that it uses SkBitmap internally.

And the Bitmap class of Android is allocating 
a native heap and a jbyte array for bitmap itself and backing buffer, respectivly.

What is the backing buffer and its goal?
(backing buffer is declaed as 'mBuffer' in the Bitmap class of Android)

Comment: Specify Question in detail. So that user understand easily